# Simplifying login for Android TV / Leanback

Tags: android, android-tv

Is there a simple(r) way to allow users to login with the Leanback library? I know there is a standard way to do it, requiring the on-screen keyboard... but is there a best-practices way to login that doesn't require the user to type from the on screen keyboard? Is there a library or a plugin that will sync with the users phone and just transfer their login details similar to how Google allows users to login to the device on initial setup? I'm just looking for ways to make my client a bit easier on end-users.

[Edit]

Accepting based on the discovery of this library:

https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use some kind of PIN code with your mobile device. For example, when user need to log in, they can choose login in TV, or enter some PIN code that display on your mobile app, which already logged in.

Comment: Saying it can be done, and providing an example of how are different things. I know Google allows for logins using a pin for their native apps. That's awesome! How can I do that though? Do they have an API for it? Is there something I can integrate into my app that gives me that same functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately, till now I cannot find any API from Google for this one. Within the same network, I use DLNA for similar task.

Comment: Today I found this stuff from LG: https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android

Comment: Okay, that library is awesome. Looks like a great starting point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use  **Nearby Connections API** which is provided by the Android team.
Using this, you can connect your device with the Android TV and after connection setup, you can share information to your TV.